# transfer value from datepicker using session to another form with the default selected value which had been selected using datepicker

Tags: zend-framework, session

hi friends i want to am using a form name check point where the user inserts his dob in datepicker how can i  fetch it using session in zend framework to display in another form with dob selevted in datepicker field by default using session in zend there is no db interation involoved here can anyone help me please

i am using dob has the name of the country field

dob = $_post['dob'];

i want the value of this dob selected in dob of datepicker by default in next form can anyone help on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Zend Session](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.basic_usage.html). In the bootstrap file you will need to [turn on sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php):

```
//bootstrap
session_start();
```

Then when you want to 'save' the date of birth info:

```
$formDob = new Zend_Session_Namespace('formDob');
$formDob->dob = $_POST['dob'];
```

And finally, when you want to use it in another form:

```
$formDob = new Zend_Session_Namespace('formDob');
$dob = $formDob->dob;
```

then you can set the value of the field using the `$dob` variable.